# Trying to put an image inside my datepicker input

Tags: jquery, css, datepicker

Im using datepicker to select a date and it is already working fine.

I also have buttonImage option to open datepicker on image click.

The problem is, that I want to put my calendar image inside my input floated at left, but I dont see how I can do this.

This is my input:

```
<input type="text" class="datepicker" id="formDate" />
```

Here I start my datepicker with some configurations:

```
$(function(){
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({   
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: 'img/calendar.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true
     });
    $('.ui-datepicker-trigger').css({padding: '7px' ,  float:'left', cursor:'pointer', background:'gray' });
});
```

Im trying to have my image inside my input, but Im not having sucess doing this.

I tried with margins, floats, giving to my image position absolute and to my input position relative and nothing is working..

Im getting always this result:

[image]

Do you see some way to put my calendar image inside my input at left?

Answer (score 3):

```
<input tpye="text" class="datepicker"/>


input.datepicker
{
  background-image : url('images/calendarp.png');
  background-Position : 97% center;
  background-Repeat :no-repeat;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It is easy for you to make simple design.
Like this.

```
<div class="form-group">
 <div class="input-group date" id="timepicker">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" />
 </div>
</div>
```

And the output is like this..

[image]

and i think it is better..

but is you really like making the icon at the background of you textbox you may use this

in HTML

```
<input type="text" id="txtSample"/>
```

in CSS

```
#txtSample
{
   background: url('calendar.png') no-repeat;
}
```

The image will vary according to its size so better to get smaller image..

I hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

a solution to your question
using jquery to do the styling and for more detail link below

here is a example:

```
<label for ="txtDOB">Date of birth</label>
    <input id="txtDOB" type="text" class="inputWithImge" />
    <img src="calendar.png" alt="Click to popup the clendar!" onclick="alert('Popup some calendar here!');" />
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".inputWithImge").each(function(){
        $(this).add($(this).next()).wrapAll('<div class="imageInputWrapper"></div>');
    }); 
});
```

css

```
.imageInputWrapper{ width:200px; border:solid 1px #000;  }
#sampleForm input.inputWithImge { width:175px; border:none; margin-right:5px;}
```